# Ensuring access to an include.php file in all enviroments

Tags: php

This question is about using PHP 'include' files in development and production environments.

Assume that the development system root folder is `www.development.com/myprogram` . Also assume that there is an '`inc`' subfolder that contains an `include.php`  file (it would be in `www.development.com/myprogram/inc` ). There are pages in the development site like `www.development.com/myprogram/index.php` and `www.development.com/myprogram/subfolder1/thispage.php`.

All pages, not matter where their location, need to 'include' the `/inc/include.php` file.

And, the production site root folder is `www.production.com` . So a page on `www.development.com/myprogram/subfolder1/thispage.php` on the development site will correspond to `www.production.com/subfolder1/thispage.php` .

How best to ensure that the `inc/include.php` file is available to all pages, on the `www.development.com` and `www.production.com` sites? Assume that  the app might be installed anywhere, not just in the root folder of a site.

Comment: Ideally, your includes don't even live in your web server's document root.

Comment: All of the includes belong to the site's root folder. And the site root folder can be anywhere. Other development sites would use different include code. Think of two site: www.dev.com/site1 and www.dev.com/site2. Each has different needs for an include file, so each site's include location has to be a subfolder of its site. Think of two sites, developing on my dev.com site, that have different CSS needs or different functions.

Comment: The best way I've seen for dealing with this issue is to route ALL of your requests through a **single php file** and have that single PHP file define the path to any includes. You can still support urls with paths by putting the paths after index.php (e.g., http://example.com/index.php?/path/to/something ) or you can use mod_rewrite to translate http://example.com/some/path/to/file to point to your index.php file with the path appended as query string. If you don't use a single PHP file as point of entry, each file must have different code to locate the includes.

Comment: What if I create a site for a client, not knowing it's ultimate location? The client could have a site-root of www.clientsite.com/here or www.clientsite/here/and/there . How do I determine the site root of those two places? And let all pages, even if at www.clientsite.com/here/and/there/and/everywhere/index.php ?

Answer (score 1):

Simply use relative file paths with `__DIR__` magic constant:

In index.php:

```
include __DIR__ . '/inc/include.php';
```

In subfolder1/thispage.php:

```
include __DIR__ . '/../inc/include.php';
```

Comment: If I load the www.development.com/subfolder/anotherfolder/thispage.php  (where development.com/subfolder is the root folder of my development/program), the __DIR__ will not work. The 'inc' folder is off of the root of the site (development.com/subfolder ) so won't work on the that thispage.php file. I need a way to specify the 'inc' folder no matter how deep I am into the site, even if the site's root is a subfolder of my domain.  I don't want to have a different include statement (your 2nd include statement) for all files. I want a 'global' that I can use anywhere in the site.